# Why does the 1/2 go away in vacuum energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, casimir-effect

This source http://www.hep.caltech.edu/%7Ephys199/lectures/lect5_6_cas.pdf on page 3 says $E_{0} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k}\omega_{k} = \sum_{k}\omega_{k}$ (Natural units are being used and $E_{0}$ is the vacuum energy)

But where did the $\frac{1}{2}$ go? On other derivations of the Casimir effect the $\frac{1}{2}$ is not removed, so why do we remove it here?

Comment: 1. The source does *not* write $\frac{1}{2}\sum_k\omega_k  = \sum_k \omega_k$. It writes $\frac{1}{2}\sum_k\sum_\lambda\omega_k = \sum_k\omega_k$ ($\hbar$ omitted). Did you perhaps just not read that equation carefully enough? 2. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning (when there is still 1/2) the sum is also over the polarizations (indicated by $\lambda$). The polarizations of lights are 2, and the frequencies do not change from one polarization to another; so the sum over the two polarizations becomes a multiplication by 2 (i.e. $\omega_{\lambda=1}+\omega_{\lambda=2}=\omega+\omega=2\omega$), and this cancels out the factor 1/2.